# Don't understand cause of this TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I've written this code and can't figure out what's the problem. It's supposed to be a pop-up window that can solve a quadratic equation `ax^2+bx+c=0` using the quadratic formula in Python.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

a= Entry(root, width=50, bg="white",
fg="black",
borderwidth=3.5,)
a.pack()
a.get()

b= Entry(root, width=50, bg="white",
fg="black",
borderwidth=3.5,)
b.pack()
b.get()

c= Entry(root, width=50, bg="white",
fg="black",
borderwidth=3.5,)
c.pack()
c.get()

Cscore=c.get()
Bscore=b.get()
Ascore=a.get()

#ax^2 + bx + c = 0
import math

def slove(Ascore,Bscore,Cscore):
    d = math.sqrt((Bscore**2)- 4*Ascore*Cscore)
    x1 = (-Bscore - d) / (2 * Ascore)
    x2 = (-Bscore + d) / (2 * Ascore)
    return x1, x2

x1, x2 = slove (Ascore ,Bscore ,Cscore)
#print("x1")
#print(x1)
#print("x2")
#print(x2)

def myClick():

    myLabel3 = Label(root,
    text="Megoldás   " + x1 + x2, borderwidth=15)
    myLabel3.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="solve",
 padx=10, pady=5, command=myClick,
 fg= "black" , bg= "white" )

myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the error message what I get after I ran it in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\matek\math_sqrtupdate.py", line 43, in <module>
    x1, x2 = slove (Ascore ,Bscore ,Cscore)
  File "c:\matek\math_sqrtupdate.py", line 37, in slove
    d = math.sqrt((Bscore**2)- 4*Ascore*Cscore)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

Before, instead of 'str' it says 'Entry' which I trided to cancel with the `Ascore,Bscore,Cscore`, but instead of 'Entry' it says 'str'. I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Your boxes are initially empty, you have to move the code inside a function and then convert it to `int`.

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell? i would remove that tag unless you have a direct reason for including it.

Comment: @CoolCloud: The  coefficients in the quadratic equation aren't limited to being integer values, so conversion to `float` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @martineau That is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of issues with your code, but the `TypeError` is being caused by this set of statements:

```
Cscore=c.get()
Bscore=b.get()
Ascore=a.get()
```

because the contents of `Entry` widgets are *strings*, not the floating point values needed to perform the calculations. You're also executing the `get()` methods at the wrong time — it shouldn't be done until the <kbd>solve</kbd> button is clicked, so I have effectively moved them into the `myClick()` callback function.

To help correct that problem I've add a helper function named `get_numeric_value()` to do the conversion for an `Entry` passed to it as an argument.

In addition to that issue I fixed several others—enough to make it runnable. *Note:* I strongly suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you're going to be using this language.

```
import math
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

a = Entry(root, width=50, bg="white",
          fg="black",
          borderwidth=3.5,)
a.pack()

b = Entry(root, width=50, bg="white",
          fg="black",
          borderwidth=3.5,)
b.pack()

c = Entry(root, width=50, bg="white",
          fg="black",
          borderwidth=3.5,)
c.pack()

def solve(Ascore, Bscore, Cscore):
    """ Solve quadratic equation: ax^2 + bx + c = 0
        and return solution values.
    """
    try:
        d = math.sqrt((Bscore**2)- 4*Ascore*Cscore)
        x1 = (-Bscore - d) / (2 * Ascore)
        x2 = (-Bscore + d) / (2 * Ascore)
        return x1, x2
    except ValueError:
        return math.nan, math.nan

def get_numeric_value(entry):
    """ Retrieve Entry's string contents and convert it to a float. """
    v = entry.get()
    return float(v) if v else 0.0

# Alternative using "walrus" operator added in Python 3.8.
#def get_numeric_value(entry):
#    """ Retrieve Entry's string contents and convert it to a float. """
#    return float(v) if (v := entry.get()) else 0.0

def myClick():
#    Ascore = get_numeric_value(a)
#    Bscore = get_numeric_value(b)
#    Cscore = get_numeric_value(c)
    Ascore, Bscore, Cscore = map(get_numeric_value, (a, b, c))

    x1, x2 = solve(Ascore, Bscore, Cscore)
    myLabel3 = Label(root, borderwidth=15,
                     text=f"Megoldás   {x1:.6f}, {x2:.6f}")
    myLabel3.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="solve",
                  padx=10, pady=5, command=myClick,
                  fg= "black", bg="white")
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm kinda new to the language Thanks for the reference I'll check it. I appreciate the new code It works just as I wanted. And really thx for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Learning the language by writing a `tkinter` app is probably one of the most challenging and difficult ways to do so—particularly given that the latter isn't very "pythonic" in many respects. Best of luck to you on your endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that all Ascore, Bscore, Cscore are numbers (not strings). Seems that  Bscore might be a string. Here is a demonstration of float vs string:

```
>>> Bscore = 2.0   
>>> Bscore**2    
4.0
>>> Bscore = '2.0' 
>>> Bscore**2      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm kinda new to the language  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it. I have known that both B-,A score was a string I just didn't know how to make them not strings. Thank u for the comment.